# Testing a Angular 9 service using Jest and Testbed

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, jestjs

In my Angular 9 project I added `jest` and removed `Jasmine` and `Karma`.

I'm testing a service called `CorrectionService` that has a dependency of a service called `RemoteService`.

I want to spy on the `RemoteService` to see if a method is called. I've successfully done it by mocking manually with jest the `RemoteService`.

Now I want to use `TestBed`. My previous Jasmine test is this:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CorrectionService } from './correction.service';
import { Answer, Question } from './setting';
import { IChoosed } from './question/question.component';
import { RemoteService } from './remote.service';


describe('CorrectionService', () => {
  let service: CorrectionService;
  let remoteServiceSpy: jasmine.SpyObj<RemoteService>

  beforeEach(() => {
    const spy = jasmine.createSpyObj('RemoteService', ['saveToRemoteAdditionalData']);
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        CorrectionService,
        {provide: RemoteService, useValue: spy}
      ]
    });
    service = TestBed.inject(CorrectionService);
    remoteServiceSpy = TestBed.inject(RemoteService) as jasmine.SpyObj<RemoteService>;
  });
```

I've tried to use `jest` mock this way:

```js
import { TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '@angular/common/http/testing';
import { HttpClient, HttpHandler } from '@angular/common/http';
import { CorrectionService } from './correction.service';
import { Answer, Question } from './setting';
import { IChoosed } from './question/question.component';
import { RemoteService } from './remote.service';


describe('CorrectionService', () => {
  let service: CorrectionService;
  this.remoteServiceStub = {} as RemoteService;

  beforeEach(() => {
    this.remoteServiceStub = {saveToRemoteAdditionalData: jest.fn()};

    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers:[
        CorrectionService,
        {provide:RemoteService, useValue: this.remoteServiceStub}
      ]
    });
    this.service = TestBed.inject(CorrectionService);
    TestBed.inject(RemoteService);
  });
```

But the tests arent working and I got:

```
 Can't resolve all parameters for CorrectionService: (?).
```

I guess `RemoteService` is not injected. What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Do both services belong to the same module? It is not clear from the code snippet, also notice you are using  `HttpClientTestingModule` in the previous test Jasmine  scenario

Comment: Yes, same module. I've edited the question to provide more info. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the problem, I had a misplaced `emitDecoratorMetadata` attribute in `tsconfig.spec.json`. It wasn't in the `compilerOptions`.

I write the full content of the file here for future reference:

```
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.json",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "./out-tsc/spec",
    "types": [
      "jest",
      "node"
    ],
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  },
  "files": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "src/polyfills.ts"
  ],
  "esModuleInterop": true,
  "include": [
    "src/**/*.spec.ts",
    "src/**/*.d.ts"
  ]
}
```

Comment: There is another issue in the tsconfig. "esModuleInterop" is a property of "compilerOptions". For more information: https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#esModuleInterop.